# Issue moving input to the right on right arrow key with jquery

Tags: jquery

I have this code :

```
jQuery.fn.enterText = function(e){
var $cursor = $("#cursor");

if (e.keyCode == 39){
    e.preventDefault();
    $cursor.val("");
var nextChar =  $cursor.next();
    $cursor.after(nextChar);
}

};
```

Im trying to move the #cursor to the right but it seems the browser does not allow it....the left arrow key works :

```
if (e.keyCode == 37){
    $cursor.val("");
var previousChar =  $cursor.prev();
    $cursor.after(previousChar);

}
```

Comment: Can you make a demo on http://jsfiddle.net so we can see what you see?

Comment: [jQuery caret positioning](http://www.google.com/#q=jquery+caret+positioning)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using `before` instead of after:

http://jsfiddle.net/Gq5HZ/1/

```
if (e.keyCode == 39) {
    $cursor.val("");
    var nextChar = $cursor.next();
    $cursor.before(nextChar);
}
```

You are trying to add the element which is after the cursor, after the cursor... it's already there.

Answer (score 0):

The left arrow key works because you're using [after()](http://api.jquery.com/after/), so you're actually *moving the previous character after the cursor element*.

I would recommend using [insertBefore()](http://api.jquery.com/insertBefore/) and [insertAfter()](http://api.jquery.com/insertAfter/) to move the cursor element instead, so your intent is clearer:

```
if (e.keyCode == 39) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $cursor.val("");
    var nextChar = $cursor.next();
    $cursor.insertAfter(nextChar);
}

if (e.keyCode == 37) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $cursor.val("");
    var previousChar = $cursor.prev();
    $cursor.insertBefore(previousChar);
}
```